# Dynamic load component inside accordion

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a project using angular. In my project am using material accordion. I am facing a problem while loading the the dynamic component inside the accordion. Here is my code:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of data;" >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header #panelH (click)="toggle(panelH,item)">
      <mat-panel-title>
       {{item.name}}
      </mat-panel-title>

    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-container #piechartsContainer></ng-container>
  </mat-expansion-panel>

</mat-accordion>
```

Inside typescript

```
 let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TcpComponent);
    let componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Nothing is loaded and not getting any error.If I write this `<ng-container #piechartsContainer></ng-container>` after mat-expionsion panel then its loaded. I want to load this inside expansion panel

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your code this last line :

```
let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TcpComponent);
let componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(componentFactory);
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // <== this one
```

And we agree that this.entry is declared like this :

```
  @ViewChild('piechartsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
```

Comment: I tried but not working and updaed the question as well

Comment: @Karan you don't need `detectChanges` if the `changeDetectionStrategy` is default. however, you do need `{static: false}` for sure otherwise it won't be check in `AfterViewInit` lifecycle.